# springboot @validated and bindingresult

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@Validated
public class AddressWebController {
    @GetMapping(value = {"/{id}")
    public String editForm(@PathVariable(value = "id") @Positive Long id, Model model) {
            // process
    }

    @PutMapping(value = {"/edit"})
    public String editProcess(@ModelAttribute @Valid Form form,
                              BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // ???
        }
        
        // process
    }
}
```

```
public class Form {
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

- curl -XGET 'http://localhost/5'

  - is pass
- curl -XGET 'http://localhost/-5'

  - A ConstraintViolationException exception is thrown. Due to @Validated and @Positive
- curl 'http://localhost/edit' --data-raw '_method=PUT&name='

  - I expected it to come in as `bindingResult.hasErrors()` in that part, but the same ConstraintViolationException is thrown.

When `@Validated` is removed, `bindingResult.hasErrors()` works, but `@Positive` annotation does not.
How can I use `@Validated` annotation and `BindingResult` together?

Comment: You cannot use those together. They operate on different levels.